# IDE with LaTeX and R support: Inline output in .Rmd notebooks and weaving LaTeX document with R code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, latex

I'm trying to improve my workflow when working with R and generating documentation. I've been going between TeXStudio, JupyterLab and RStudio for a while, and I'm trying to improve my workflow. TeXStudio has limited R support, and RStudio limited support for LaTeX.

VS Code has support for multiple languages, including R and LaTeX. The fact that it can run both Jupyter notebooks, R notebooks, and LaTeX, and has plugins for other languages as well, makes it seem desirable. However, I am unable to find documentation on how to configure it to work with R and LaTeX code in the same file. In addition, I am unable to configure R notebooks to allow inline code execution output.

However, I am unable to *(a)* set up **code execution output under the code for .Rmd notebooks**, and *(b)* I can't figure out **how to weave .Rnw (R/LaTeX) documents with Sweave/knitr**.

I'm trying to find an IDE that would include features like:

- Markdown, code and code execution output in the same document
- Auto R and LaTeX code completion
- Automatic display of R function documentation
- Spell check
- Simple R console access
- Compile .Rnw
- Syntax highlighting for both R code and LaTeX code

I am, primarily, requesting ways to configure VS Code, or, secondly, way to configure another IDE that can meet my requirements. A tutorial on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hmm.  RStudio does have *basic* syntax highlighting for LaTeX (i.e. it recognizes LaTeX reserved words and typesets them in blue), although it doesn't e.g. highlight math mode: the highlighting rules are [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/c727a0c108376f7108dc835d7a4f22ccaf99f0f6/src/gwt/acesupport/acemode/tex_highlight_rules.js) and might be hackable/pull requests might be considered?

Comment: Also doesn't do code completion for LaTeX (code completion stuff seems deeper, maybe [here](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/tree/c727a0c108376f7108dc835d7a4f22ccaf99f0f6/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/cpp) ?).  But it does the rest (R docs, TeX-aware spellcheck, R console access ...) (I know you didn't ask "How do I hack RStudio to get it do what I want?").  Building Rnw seems straightforward, i.e. `knitr::knit2pdf()`?

Comment: @BenBolker I noticed the recent versions of RStudion can do basic syntax highlighting, but not code completion. Conversely, TeXStudio provides highlighting and autocompletion of LaTeX syntax, but not R.

Comment: @BenBolker Unfortunately, I lack the time and ability to work on how to hack RStudio.

Comment: That seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Have you looked at Emacs?  I don't use it, but I know it supports both R and LaTeX, I just don't know if it does all the things you need.  My preference is to use RStudio for R and TeXworks for LaTex (and knitr in Sweave mode).

Comment: @user2554330 No, I haven't tried Emacs. From what I could figure out, it didn't seem like the interactive environment I was looking for. How is TeXWorks' support for highlighting and autocompletion of R code?

Comment: TeXWorks is designed as a LaTeX IDE, and it doesn't do any autocompletion of R at all.  However, it is flexible enough that it can be configured to process Rnw files using Sweave or knitr.  So when I'm mainly working on the LaTeX part of a document, I use it; when I'm mainly working on the R part, I use RStudio.

Comment: @user2554330 Ah, ok. I've seen guides for a similar approach with TeXStudio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of digging around, I found that VS Code does nearly all the things I need.

- Auto R and LaTeX code completion, Display of R function documentation in a tab in VS Code, Simple R console access, and Syntax highlighting for both R code and LaTeX code:

The [R](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ikuyadeu.r) and [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extensions, will provide highlighting and autocompletion of code in both languages. By installing R, you can easily open a session in a terminal window in VS Code, and from there open documentation inside VS Code.

- Spell check

[Code Spell Checker](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker) offers spell check for multiple languages. Install the extension and any desired dictionaries, and set the langauges you want to be included in the extension settings.

- Compile .Rnw files

Turns out LaTeX Workshop can actually do this by default.

- Markdown, code and code execution output in the same document

This is the only thing VS Code doesn't do as far as I can tell. It can compile .Rmd files, however, but the output can only be seen in the compiled PDF. I consider this less important, since I can use Jupyter notebooks instead.